# TreeViewItem.HeaderTemplate and moving across the tree

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, treeviewitem

there

This is my code behind, it may seem a little bit odd

```
class DataContext
    {
        ObservableCollection<TreeViewItem> itemsSource;
        public ObservableCollection<TreeViewItem> ItemsSource
        {
            get { return this.itemsSource; }
            set { this.itemsSource = value; }
        }
    }

        ObservableCollection<TreeViewItem> items = new ObservableCollection<TreeViewItem>();

        items.Add(new TreeViewItem());
        DataContext dcs = new DataContext();
        dcs.ItemsSource = new ObservableCollection<TreeViewItem>();

        dcs.ItemsSource.Add(new TreeViewItem());
        dcs.ItemsSource[dcs.ItemsSource.Count - 1] = null;
        dcs.ItemsSource.Add(new TreeViewItem());
        dcs.ItemsSource[dcs.ItemsSource.Count - 1] = null;
        dcs.ItemsSource.Add(new TreeViewItem());
        dcs.ItemsSource[dcs.ItemsSource.Count - 1] = null;
        dcs.ItemsSource.Add(new TreeViewItem());
        dcs.ItemsSource[dcs.ItemsSource.Count - 1] = null;
        dcs.ItemsSource.Add(new TreeViewItem());
        dcs.ItemsSource[dcs.ItemsSource.Count - 1] = null;
        dcs.ItemsSource.Add(new TreeViewItem());
        dcs.ItemsSource[dcs.ItemsSource.Count - 1] = null;


        items[items.Count - 1].DataContext = dcs;

        items.Add(new TreeViewItem());
        items[items.Count - 1].DataContext = null;
        items.Add(new TreeViewItem());
        items[items.Count - 1].DataContext = null;
        items.Add(new TreeViewItem());
        items[items.Count - 1].DataContext = null;
        items.Add(new TreeViewItem());
        items[items.Count - 1].DataContext = null;
        items.Add(new TreeViewItem());
        items[items.Count - 1].DataContext = null;
        items.Add(new TreeViewItem());
        items[items.Count - 1].DataContext = null;
        items.Add(new TreeViewItem());
        items[items.Count - 1].DataContext = null;
        items.Add(new TreeViewItem());
        items[items.Count - 1].DataContext = null;



        DataContext dc = new DataContext();
        dc.ItemsSource = items;

        MyTreeView.DataContext = dc;
```

I have this code in my xaml

```
<TreeView x:Name="MyTreeView" Margin="0" ItemsSource="{Binding ItemsSource}">
        <TreeView.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="TreeViewItem">
                <Setter Property="HeaderTemplate">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <CheckBox IsChecked="True" Focusable="False"/>
                                <TextBlock Text="Text"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
                <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding ItemsSource}"/>
                <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="True"/>
            </Style>
        </TreeView.Resources>
    </TreeView>
```

there is a problem with TreeViewItem subnodes, I cannot use up & down arrows to move between them. Please, advise me what should I do. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to SO. You should post a minimal but completely functional code sample of your `TreeView`, with items, etc. Something that exposes the problem and can be pasted in a tool like kaxaml.

Comment: I tried your style and I can normally use up and down arrows to move between TreeViewItems. Maybe you should post more details about your code.

Comment: ok, I've corrected my post

Answer (score 0):

In order to solve your problem, TreeViewItems in your code should be added directly to the `Items` property. Something like that:

```
TreeViewItem treeViewItem = new TreeViewItem();
treeViewItem.Items.Add(new TreeViewItem());
treeViewItem.Items.Add(new TreeViewItem());
treeViewItem.Items.Add(new TreeViewItem());

MyTreeView.Items.Add(new TreeViewItem());
MyTreeView.Items.Add(treeViewItem);
MyTreeView.Items.Add(new TreeViewItem());
```

Anyway I suggest you to deepen how WPF works and the to completely revise your code.
You can start from [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750612(v=vs.110).aspx) and [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745683(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Thanks, I removed binding in xaml and assigned `TreeViewItem.ItemsSource = ds.ItemsSource` in code and it solved the problem. I don't think that it's possible for me to determine the reason of such strange behavior because it's binded to a internal work of wpf

Comment: I am happy you found the solution